# Is there any way to use the generic protocol as a data type in a function?

Tags: swift, types, interface, protocols

Is there any way to use the generic protocol as a data type in a function?

```
public protocol ICRUDOperation {

    associatedtype T

    func insert(data:T)
    func update(data:T)
    func get(data:T) -> [T]
    func GetList(data: BaseModel) -> Array<T>
    func GetPage(data: BaseModel) -> Array<T>
    func Delete(data: T)
}
```

In the below function, I get the Error

```
func Delegate1<W: ICRUDOperation>(sqlite: W, service: W, data: T) {
    sqlite.insert(data: data)
}
```

> error: Cannot convert value of type 'T' (generic parameter of generic
>   class 'Decision') to expected argument type 'W.T' (associated type of
>   protocol 'ICRUDOperation')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error stated, `T` is a generic parameter whose class is not defined in function declaration because `T` is associated with `ICRUDOperation` so you should use your delegate as:

```
func Delegate1<W: ICRUDOperation>(sqlite: W, service: W, data: W.T) {
    sqlite.insert(data: data)
}
```